# On Ethereum private chain, why my light node cannot connect to the bootnode?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, light-clients

I'm new to ethereum and geth client, and I met some trouble nowadays. I do need someone's help.

I try to setup an ethereum private chain, which includes full nodes, light nodes, and bootnodes. The aim to use bootnodes is that I want these nodes can discover each other through the bootnodes, but it failed even no full nodes participating yet.

**Firstly**, I use the following command to start a bootnode:

```
bootnode -nodekey myboot.key --verbosity 6
```

And then I got the following response:

```
enode://<enode thing>@127.0.0.1:0?discport=30301
```

**Secondly**, I start a geth client in light mode:

```
geth --identity node2 --datadir data0 --http --http.api eth,net,web3 --http.addr 127.0.0.1 --http.port 20001 -port 30002 --networkid <networkid> --bootnodes "enode://<enode thing>" --syncmode "light" --allow-insecure-unlock --verbosity 5
```

**Then, I got the following response in light node:**

```
INFO [09-10|05:36:16.552] Started P2P networking                   self=enode://e09b02074f9e3575cebebca98f3dc8ad0c8775b569650fd1fa1d56cdd2080b0fa42b82d222bd211230579fd869eb9ad59db035c10eff84f45bcdc3e63d4247d3@127.0.0.1:30002
TRACE[09-10|05:36:16.553] Found seed node in database              id=e7e0241db496f723 addr=172.17.0.3:30301 age=461885h36m16.553745693s
TRACE[09-10|05:36:16.553] >> FINDNODE/v5                           id=e7e0241db496f723 addr=172.17.0.3:30301
TRACE[09-10|05:36:17.255] FINDNODE failed                          id=e7e0241db496f723 failcount=1 dropped=false err="RPC timeout"
TRACE[09-10|05:36:17.255] >> FINDNODE/v5                           id=e7e0241db496f723 addr=172.17.0.3:30301
TRACE[09-10|05:36:17.956] FINDNODE failed                          id=e7e0241db496f723 failcount=1 dropped=false err="RPC timeout"
TRACE[09-10|05:36:17.957] >> FINDNODE/v5                           id=e7e0241db496f723 addr=172.17.0.3:30301
DEBUG[09-10|05:36:18.652] Couldn't add port mapping                proto=tcp extport=30002 intport=30002 interface="UPnP or NAT-PMP" err="no UPnP or NAT-PMP router discovered"
DEBUG[09-10|05:36:18.653] Couldn't add port mapping                proto=udp extport=30002 intport=30002 interface="UPnP or NAT-PMP" err="no UPnP or NAT-PMP router discovered"
TRACE[09-10|05:36:18.657] FINDNODE failed                          id=e7e0241db496f723 failcount=2 dropped=false err="RPC timeout"
TRACE[09-10|05:36:18.658] >> FINDNODE/v5                           id=e7e0241db496f723 addr=172.17.0.3:30301
TRACE[09-10|05:36:19.360] FINDNODE failed                          id=e7e0241db496f723 failcount=2 dropped=false err="RPC timeout"
TRACE[09-10|05:36:19.360] >> FINDNODE/v5                           id=e7e0241db496f723 addr=172.17.0.3:30301
TRACE[09-10|05:36:20.062] FINDNODE failed                          id=e7e0241db496f723 failcount=3 dropped=false err="RPC timeout"
TRACE[09-10|05:36:20.062] >> PING/v5                               id=e7e0241db496f723 addr=172.17.0.3:30301
DEBUG[09-10|05:36:20.764] Removed dead node                        b=15 id=e7e0241db496f723 ip=172.17.0.3 checks=0
TRACE[09-10|05:36:20.764] >> FINDNODE/v5                           id=e7e0241db496f723 addr=172.17.0.3:30301
TRACE[09-10|05:36:21.466] FINDNODE failed                          id=e7e0241db496f723 failcount=3 dropped=false err="RPC timeout"
TRACE[09-10|05:36:21.466] >> FINDNODE/v5                           id=e7e0241db496f723 addr=172.17.0.3:30301
TRACE[09-10|05:36:22.166] FINDNODE failed                          id=e7e0241db496f723 failcount=4 dropped=false err="RPC timeout"
```

**I got the following response in bootnode:**

```
DEBUG[09-10|05:36:16.554] Bad discv4 packet                        addr=172.17.0.2:30002 err="too small"
DEBUG[09-10|05:36:17.255] Bad discv4 packet                        addr=172.17.0.2:30002 err="too small"
DEBUG[09-10|05:36:17.956] Bad discv4 packet                        addr=172.17.0.2:30002 err="too small"
DEBUG[09-10|05:36:18.658] Bad discv4 packet                        addr=172.17.0.2:30002 err="too small"
DEBUG[09-10|05:36:19.360] Bad discv4 packet                        addr=172.17.0.2:30002 err="too small"
DEBUG[09-10|05:36:20.062] Bad discv4 packet                        addr=172.17.0.2:30002 err="too small"
DEBUG[09-10|05:36:20.764] Bad discv4 packet                        addr=172.17.0.2:30002 err="too small"
DEBUG[09-10|05:36:21.466] Bad discv4 packet                        addr=172.17.0.2:30002 err="too small"
```

I can't figure out what's going on.

And there is **another question** that really confuses me:
I start a light node and a full node with `light.server 70` flag. And then I use admin.addPeer() function in full node to connect the light node, and it succeeds. But the strange thing is the full node cannot advertise the light node peer to other full nodes it connected. I expected that the light node could connect to other full nodes, but it didn't.

**If anyone knows anything about my question, please leave an answer. I would be very thankful to you all kind friends.**

**And if there is anything unclear, please let me know and I will add more details.**